# Parent LinearLayout onclick, not called from child recyclerview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout, with many children views, including a recyclerview. I want the **entire** parent view to be clickable, and when the chidren are clicked I want the same thing to happen. ie I want that where ever you click in the parent view, the method will be called.

Now this is working fine, and whenever you click in the parent the method is called. Except the recycler view, that when I click there, nothing happens. I tried setting clickable and focusable of the recyclerview view to true and false, and it still didn't work.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onTodayMainPageClick"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/date_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="1st October 2017"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whats_left_for_today_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:text="Whats left for today"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/today_recycler_view_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing it in following way,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_main"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="1st October 2017"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whats_left_for_today_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:text="Whats left for today"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/today_recycler_view_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#eee"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/clickable_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_main"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onTodayMainPageClick"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/linear_main"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/linear_main"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linear_main" />
```